# Get all the elements in one list that does not exist in another list by dynamic arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying [dynamic arrays](https://blog-insider.office.com/2019/06/13/dynamic-arrays-and-new-functions-in-excel/), and wonder if it changes the way of achieving some of my basic tasks.

For example, given a list of strings A1:A10 and another list of strings C1:C10, I could use **one** very complex Ctrl+Shift+Enter (CSE) array formulas to retrieve **all the elements in A1:10 that does not exist in C1:C10**.

Does anyone know if dynamic arrays can achieve this in just one formula?

**Edit:** I was not very clear in the beginning, I want to use only **one** formula to output the result list, and I want the list to not contain empty...

[image]

Comment: The google sheets equivalent to these dynamic arrays would be `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,ISNA(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0))))`, so I assume (I am not a 365 insider, so can't test it), you can try in C2: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),ISNA(MATCH(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),0))))`

Answer (score 0):

**This array formula, dynamically gets value from `Column F` are not in `Column G`:**

**Caveat:**

- Shown array formula works with all versions of Excel 2010, and higher.
- *Dynamic Array Functions* supports Excel 2019 & Excel 365 only.

[image]

- Formula in Cell `H2`:

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH("ZZZ",$F:$F)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($F$1:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH("ZZZ",$F:$F)))/(COUNTIF($G$2:INDEX($G:$G,MATCH("ZZZ",$G:$G)),$F$2:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH("ZZZ",$F:$F)))=0),ROW(1:1))),"")}`

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**,& drag down.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Sorry, I would want the unique list not to contain empty... Please see the update in OP...

Comment: @SoftTimur,, oh man you have given twist to the question after is been replied,, okay tell me if I get unique list in another Column works for you or you want solution in single Column?

Comment: I want solution in only one column and one formula (which can be repeated several times).

Comment: @SoftTimur,, okay give me some time to recreate whole!!

Comment: @SoftTimur, **Edit** your post & remove `Wang` from Third Column since is common in both!!

Comment: that's true....

Comment: Thank you, Excel guru... So to answer my question, don't you think dynamic arrays could simplify your array formulas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97549/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-softtimur).